# MySQL query IF EXISTS ELSE IF ELSE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a simple, IF, ELSE IF, ELSE statement which fairly easy in SQL.
for some reason it will not listen to me in MySQL.
It keeps telling me 'Read the fucking manual' altho the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

does not state how to do this in the SELECT part, only after the where, which I would assume means I cannot do this the way I am used to do this.
The question remaining is, how would I do it then?

```
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `content` WHERE `ResourceKey`='Test' AND `Language`='en-GB') 
THEN
    SELECT `Text` FROM `content` WHERE `ResourceKey`='Test' AND `Language`='en-GB'; 
ELSE 
    SELECT `Text` FROM `content` WHERE `ResourceKey`='Test' AND `Language`='nl-NL';
END IF;
```

Also some info:

`Innodb version: 1.1.8`
`Protocol version: 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect one record from your query, then there is no need to use an `IF ELSE` statement for this. Try this instead:

```
SELECT `Text` 
FROM `content` 
WHERE `ResourceKey`='Test' AND `Language` ΙΝ ('en-GB', 'nl-NL');
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN `Language` = 'en-GB' THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
         END
LIMIT 1
```

In case you want to *always* return some text, even when no record is returned, then use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.Text, 'No record found') AS Text
FROM (
   SELECT 'en-GB' AS lang UNION ALL 'nl-NL' UNION ALL 'no-lang') AS t1
LEFT JOIN content AS t2 
   ON t1.lang = t2.Language AND t2.ResourceKey = 'Test'  
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN t1.lang = 'en-GB' THEN 1 
            WHEN t1.lang = 'nl-NL' THEN 2
            ELSE 3         -- This is the case where t1.lang = 'no-lang'
         END
LIMIT 1
```

I assume there is no record in your database having `Language = 'no-lang'`.

Comment: Hmm this is much sexier than I anticipated, and yeah there should be only 1 returned (`ResourceKey` + language = unique) on extension to the function, how would I return a simple text if neither has been found?

Comment: Also, IN is not supported in my database.

Comment: The languages in the `Language` column are FKéd to a table with languages and their real names and all 2 char - 2 char I don't believe this would be a problem :)
The code still has errors on my database it says: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nl-NL' UNION ALL 'no-lang') AS t1
LEFT JOIN content AS t2 
   ON t1.lang = t2' at line 3 *

Comment: I fired this baby at a MyISAM DB, no problems at all, it seems that my InnoDB isn't allowed to do this?

Comment: I have accepted you answer because of the great explanation as final query I have wrote: FROM (SELECT 'en-GB' AS lang UNION ALL

      SELECT 'nl-NL'         UNION ALL

      SELECT 'no-lang') AS t1

LEFT JOIN content AS t2 ON t1.lang =t2.Language AND t2.ResourceKey = 'Test'

ORDER BY OrderKey

LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Text` 
FROM `content` 
WHERE `ResourceKey` = 'Test'
AND `Language` ΙΝ ('en-GB', 'nl-NL')
ORDER BY if (`Language` = 'en-GB', 1, 2)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to explain why 1 + 1 = 2 not 3 :)

Comment: I have accept @giorgos his answer because his explanation was explicit and IN does not work on my version of MySQL.